A [rad] burnination proposal
As the rad tag wiki says: "Please don't use this tag, it is ambiguous."
Related: Clarify [rad] tag. I don't think it should be clarified but burninated, however, since the tag doesn't really add meaningful information to the post. Existing posts could be re-tagged if needed.
It could either mean:

Rapid Application Development (tool), a group of programming IDEs which eases GUI design, for example Delphi, VB, QT etc.
IBM Rational Application Developer, which has its own tag ibm-rad. There's also the related websphere tag.
RAD studio was the IDE tool name for the line of Borland products that ended up as Embarcadero, most famously Delphi and C++ Builder. All of these products have their own tags like delphi or c++builder.
Rad is used as a prefix for various components in .net, telerik etc.
Remote Access Descriptor is apparently a term used by Oracle Platforms Security Services.

The majority of posts using the tag are either about IMB Rational products or the Embarcadero products, but some of the other uses mentioned above also pop up here and there.

Burnination criteria

Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It is very ambiguous.

Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

I think most of the ambiguous uses are on-topic, particularly the general term rapid application development.
But if we are to preserve the tag to only mean rapid application development in general, then at least the tag wiki needs to be recrafted and include tag usage policies.

Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.

Other related discussions/burninations:
This tag is not [rational]  (maybe it should be merged with ibm-rad?)
Someone is retagging a bunch of old embarcadero questions

My first thought was that this was for questions about doing trigonometry in radians.

Dooooood! That tag is raaaaaadical!

A modest burnination proposal.

@KarlKnechtel That might be yet another supposed meaning of the tag I guess, though I saw no posts about radians. I didn't check all 500+ posts though.

There are hardly any rad questions anymore anyway. All dupes and stinkers.

@AndrewGrimm As in A Modest Proposal for Preventing the Children of Poor People from Being a Burthen to Their Parents or Country, and for Making Them Beneficial to the Publick? :)

E[rad]idicate !

Burnination puns aside, does anyone got any feedback to offer about the actual contents of the question?
